# switchery button on change values

Tags: javascript, php

[image]I am trying to get values Y and N on change switchery button, but with the following piece of codes whatever I've written, I am getting 'Y' all the time. please help

```
        var lang_dis_button = document.querySelector('.lang-disable');
        var lang_disable = new Switchery(lang_dis_button, { color: '#ED5565' });

        var changeStatus = document.querySelector('.lang-disable')
          , changeField = document.querySelector('#disabled_status');

        changeStatus.onchange = function() {
          if (changeStatus.checked) {
            changeField.innerHTML = 'Disabled';
          } else {
            changeField.innerHTML = 'Active';
          }
        };

     <input type="checkbox" class="lang-disable" name="disabled" id="disabled" value="Y" 
         <?php IF ($disabled == 'Y') { ?> checked><label id="disabled_status">Disabled</label><?php } 
           else { ?><label id="disabled_status">Active<?php } ?></label>
```

Comment: What is `$disabled`? And are you missing a `</script>` above the input element?

Comment: $disabled brings a value(Y/N) from the database. I am trying to add this switchery on the screen to get the values onchange. Thanks